# How do I index an element from an array consisting of arrays in purescript?

Tags: purescript

> a = [ 1, 2, 3]
>   a
>   [1,2,3]
>
> b = [ 3, 4, 5]
>   b
>   [3,4,5]
>
> c = [a ,b]
>   c
>   [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
>
> a !! 2
>   (Just 3)
>
> a !! 2
>   (Just 3)
>
> a !! 1
>   (Just 2)
>
> c !! 2
>   Nothing
>
> c !! 1
>   (Just [3,4,5])
>
> c !! 1 !! 0
>   Error found:
>   in module $PSCI
>   at  line 1, column 1 - line 1, column 11

Could not match type

```
Maybe
```

with type

```
Array
```

while trying to match type Maybe (Array Int)
  with type Array t0
while checking that expression (index c) 1
  has type Array t0
in value declaration it

where t0 is an unknown type

Answer (score 4):

Indexing into an array returns not the plain element, but values wrapped in `Maybe`, because the array might not have an element at the given index. In your case, the result of `c !! 1` has type `Maybe (Array Int)`. So you have to handle that `Maybe` somehow.

I guess you expect the end result to be of type `Maybe Int`. There are different ways to do so. The perhaps most explicit one is:

```
case c !! 1 of
  Nothing  -> Nothing
  (Just x) -> x !! 0
```

(this will return `Just 3`)

Because "chaining" functions like this is very common, there are abstractions that lead to the same result, e.g.:

```
(c !! 1) >>= (_ !! 0)
```

Anyways, the trick is to reach into the first result (if it was successful) and then try the second indexing. If both succeed, return the end result. If one fails, return `Nothing`.